# Django filter_horizontal in form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In admin definition attribute filter_horizontal can be specified,
that creates cool javascript using widget for ManyToMany field. I
would like to use such widget in my Model form. How can I specify this?

Comment: It would help if you could add some code of your model(s)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whats easiest way to use filter\_horizontal outside of the Admin in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778143/whats-easiest-way-to-use-filter-horizontal-outside-of-the-admin-in-django)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.hoboes.com/Mimsy/hacks/replicating-djangos-admin/reusing-djangos-filter_horizontal/