# Django model form with m2m field only showing one select box even im using FilteredSelectMultiple as the widget

Tags: python, django

Django model form with m2m field only showing one select box even im using FilteredSelectMultiple as the widget for that field . required admin filesbase files are added

```
class ExamForm(forms.ModelForm):

question_m2m = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Question.objects.all(),
                                         label=('Select Question'),
                                         widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
                                             ('question'),
                                             False,
                                         ))
class Meta:
    model=Exam
    fields = ('question_m2m',)
```

and static files are aded in base template

```
 <link href="{% static 'css/theme.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.init.js' %}"></script>
{{ examform.media }}
{{form.media}}
```

[image: here is what Im getting]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [filter_horizontal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal) for the django admin. If that is the case, you should add the forms to an admin:

```
class ExamFormAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ExamForm
    ...
```

If you would like to use `filter_horizontal` outside of the admin interface, you have to include the corresponding static files yourself, which is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778143/whats-easiest-way-to-use-filter-horizontal-outside-of-the-admin-in-django).